# Oracle .Net ManagedDatabaseAccess CLOB very slow

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle-manageddataaccess, oracle.manageddataaccess

I have two databases (10g and 11g).
I connect to the databases via C# like this:

```
var con = new OracleConnection("data source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = MYHOST)(PORT = MYPORT)) ) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER=DEDICATED) (SID = MYSID)));user id=MYUSER;password=MYPW");
var cmd = new OracleCommand("select id,clob_field from some_table", con);
cmd.InitialLOBFetchSize = -1;
using ( var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader() )
{
    while ( reader.Read() )
    {
        var id = reader.GetInt32(0);
        var clob = reader.GetString(1);
    }
    reader.Close();
}
```

The table has about 15000 rows where average CLOB size is 10KB. The code above takes like 1min per 100 rows. Both databases have the same issue.

If I comment the line "var clob = ..." then I get a very good performance.

I have tried to split the query with `dbms_lob.substr(clob_field,4000,1) where length(clob_field)<=4000` and got 1-3k rows in few seconds. But the other part (remaing 3-4k rows) took about 10 minutes.

Executing the query in SQLDeveloper returns all data in few seconds (less than 1 second per 1000 rows).

Can anyone help me to get a reasonable performance?

Comment: Are you sure that SQLDeveloper fetches immediately the CLOB and not when you "click" it on the GUI?

Comment: It fetches 100 rows. When I scroll down it fetches the next 100 rows. I kept scrolling down untill I got all 15k rows. That happened after ~30 seconds.

Comment: Does it also fetch the CLOB content or does it shows something like "CLOB" in the grid and then actually fetches it when you click on it?

Comment: It does fetch the CLOB field. But I do not know how to check if it contains all data or just first 4k bytes. In MS SQL Server I can see how many bytes have been transferred (client statistics). I am missing this feature in SQL Developer.